How to install delve(debugger for golang) on ubuntu?
The problem is that according to the instructions in the repository(https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/installation/README.md) I can not install delve, but through "sudo apt install -y delve" everything works, but not the latest version is inserted, and I need the latest version.
(ubuntu 22.04)

Does this answer your question? Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?

Why can't you install delve using the instructions you linked to?

Because it won't install. I don't know why. After go install nothing happens

No output isn't the same as nothing happens. Which is it, no output or nothing happens?

I solved the problem by following the tutorial here https://gist.github.com/missinglink/4212a81a7d9c125b68d9 You can then install the latest delv as per documentation
